# Careless Mailing Clerk Problem/Puzzle

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

So, it goes like this:

`After a typist has written ten letters and had addressed the ten corresponding envelopes, a careless mailing clerk inserted the letters in the envelopes at random, one letter per envelope. What is the probability that exactly nine letters were inserted in the proper envelopes?`

The correct answer is supposed to be that the probability of "exactly nine letters were inserted/mailed correctly" is zero (0)?

*I'm not sure how to get at this conclusion mathematically*... probability was never my forte.

Intuitively, the Pr(exactly nine letters were mailed correctly) = 0 because "If nine letters are in the correct envelopes, the tenth must/will be also, so the probability is zero."

But does that mean that the probability distribution for this is discontinuous?

(Apparently this is an old problem from the "Mathematical Quickies" by C. W. Trigg, I don't have the book but found out online)

Comment: The distribution is discrete. Your solution is correct. If an event is impossible, then its probability is zero.

Comment: See the table of [rencontres numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rencontres_numbers) - the second highest diagonal is zero

Comment: @voldemort Yes my lord. But how does one "formally" prove it impossible? It is proved impossible by the mere fact that getting all 9 correct is the the same as getting all 10?

Comment: @CesarDV: Yes. Prove it by contradiction. Suppose 10th letter is not in the right slot. It must be in nth slot then- where n<10. But then where did the nth letter go? Not in its own slot, as that's occupied! So, at most 8 letters were placed correctly- contradiction to the fact that at least 9 letters were placed correctly.

Comment: @Henry Okay thanks, I see I need to extend the table on that page a bit. But I think I understand it now...

Comment: @voldemort Thank you my lord, we're not worthy of your presence in the comments! haha :) Ok I got it, thanks! You could have written the answer and I would have selected it!

Comment: @CesarDV: I am glad to help. Don't worry- will type my answer for your next question :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are exactly nine matches, then it means the remaining one is not-matched, but this is impossible. Thus, the required probability is 0.

Comment: As noted earlier in the comments.

Comment: Right. Just want to help.

Comment: And what you have done is helpful. But acknowledging the contents of the comments would have been polite.

Comment: @Mick I'll select your answer since it's right, the only written/submitted one... (and you have less rep points than Lord Voldemort...) but don't blame me if the last thing you see is a flash of green light... ;)